# How to fix the error i am getting while running SQL Cipher project?

Tags: ios, sqlcipher

I followed the tutorial [SQLCipher tutorial](http://sqlcipher.net/ios-tutorial/) from beginning to end.

Still i am getting 3 issues when i try to build the project.
Please check the image below
[image: Error Description]

Note: The libraries libcrypto.a and libsqlcipher.a are red in color. Does this an issue.
Please check the image below 
[image: Link binary with Libraries]
Can anyone please help me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Red colors indicate that Xcode cannot find the file.

If the red file is the product of another project, build it first (probably by adding a dependency to make it automatically build.)

If the red file is the product of another target of the current project, be sure it builds first.

If the red file is one you are supplying to the project, but sure the paths are correct.  You might delete the file and re-add it as an easy way to do this.

Comment: The red file is product of another project that i imported to this project.It is showing error when i build it

Comment: If the red file is the product of a sub-project (one project referenced inside another project) there are 2 possible problems:  (1). The sub-project does not have a configuration that matches the configuration chosen in the main project. The main project will pass the configuration name to the sub-project. If there is no match then "Release" will be built.   (2). The sub-project's product is not being created in a folder expected by the outer project.  (Check the various paths in the main project settings.)

Comment: Shall i share you the code, so you can fix it easily